# How set python shell arguments with python-mode.el?

Tags: python, repl

When I use default inferior shell I can set something like this:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python"
    python-shell-interpreter-args "-i /absolute/path/to/manage.py shell_plus")
```

How set this with `python-mode.el`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Sample configuration:

```el
(setq-default
 py-shell-name          "python" ; \ Default value under Unices
 py-python-command      "python" ; /
 py-python-command-args '("-i" "/absolute/path/to/manage.py" "shell_plus"))
```

#### Elaboration

Being the package's maintainer, Andreas Röhler's [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30030/15748) is of course entirely correct and based on the project's [`README`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/python-mode/blob/master/README.org).

I recommend you read section [`Selecting a Python shell`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/python-mode/blob/master/README.org#selecting-a-python-shell) from this file, but perhaps I can elaborate on what I think you are looking for:

- The customisable variable `py-shell-name` is the path to the default python executable that gets run when you invoke `M-x py-shell` (which command is bound to `C-c !` by default).
- `python-mode.el` defines multiple customisable variables for holding python interpreter arguments:

  - `py-python-command-args`
  - `py-python2-command-args`
  - `py-python3-command-args`
  - `py-ipython-command-args`

  Which one takes effect depends on the value of `py-shell-name` and/or any [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in your source file. The shebang also determines which interpreter gets selected amongst the customisable variables

  - `py-python-command`
  - `py-python2-command`
  - `py-python3-command`
  - `py-ipython-command`

  Variables `py-python-command` and `py-python-command-args` are the fallback when the other flavours of python executable are not detected.

This is my understanding following a cursory glance at the package's source, so I might have misunderstood or missed something.

Either way, I recommend you read the project's [`README`](https://github.com/emacsmirror/python-mode/blob/master/README.org) and have a look at the settings in `M-x customize-group RET python-mode RET`.

Answer (score 0):

Customize default Python shell as `py-shell-name'

`py-shell-name' might be an installed default executable as shell
  command`type' would display, but also a PATH/TO/EXECUTABLE

If different flavours of Python are installed, customize
  py-python-command versions

```
  py-python-command (default)
  py-python2-command
  py-python3-command
  py-ipython-command

  py-python-command-args
  py-python2-command-args
  py-python3-command-args
  py-ipython-command-args
```

Comment: It must looks like this?
`(setq py-shell-name "python"
                         py-python-command-args "-i /absolute/path/to/manage.py shell_plus")`

Comment: @CryptoManiac No. BTW with python-mode.el no customization should be needed for basic use. Just call M-x python RET, resp. M-x pythonVERSION RET. In case of questions: https://answers.launchpad.net/python-mode, menu Answers